# Dependency injection with @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring

Suppose the following code:

```
@Service
public class SearchService {

    @Autowired
    DependencyService dependencyService;
}

@Service
public class DependencyService {
    private final Util util;


    DependencyService(Util util){
        this.util = util;
        execute();
    }
    public void execute(){
        util.execte();
    }


}
@Component
public class ConcreteUtil implements Util{
    @Override
    public void execte() {
        System.out.println("I'm the first concrete Util");
    }
}
@Component
public class SecondConcreteUtil implements Util{
    @Override
    public void execte() {
        System.out.println("I'm the second concrete Util");

    }
}
```

In Plain Java I can do something like this:

```
public class SearchService {


    DependencyService first = new DependencyService(new ConcreteUtil());
    DependencyService second = new DependencyService(new SecondConcreteUtil());

}
```

But in Spring, it's not resolved by the client. We instruct Spring which bean to take from inside DependencyService:

```
   DependencyService(@Qualifier("concreteUtil")Util util){
        this.util = util;
        execute();
    }
```

And not like that:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("concreteUtil")
 DependencyService dependencyService;
```

Why? To me this approach sounds like the opposite of decoupling. What do I miss? And how can Plain Java's result be achieved?

Edit:
I want this behaviour

```
public class SomeSerice {
 
    DependencyService firstConcrete = new DependencyService(new ConcreteUtil());
}

public class OtherService {
 
    DependencyService SecondConcrete = new DependencyService(new SecondConcreteUtil());
}
```

So I can reuse the code

Comment: Why do you think one is different from the other? In plain java you manually create `DependencyService` with `Util` instance of your choice, with spring `DependencyService` is created for you, again with `Util` instance of your choice. The only difference is where the instances come from.

Comment: Because I cannot have two `DependencyService` at the same time, but with different Util instances.

Comment: The number of instances of `DependencyService` has nothing to do with coupling/decoupling, and you can have as many as you want, each using different `Util`, as long as you declare the beans.

Comment: @Chaosfire "as long as you declare the beans" -- I think the OP is asking _how_ to do that.

Comment: @Slaw Well, yeah, looks like this is the real question, but that was not clear (at least for me) before OP added the example code of what he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare multiple beans of type Dependency service inside some configuration class, like

```
@Qualifier("ConcreteUtilDepService")
@Bean
public DependencyService concreteUtilDS(@Qualifier("ConcreteUtil")Util util){
   return new DependencyService (util);
}
```